# What security guarantees do blockchains provide for data storage?

Tags: hash, integrity

When it's considered, like [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86304/555)

> a project where a user needs to store a (small piece of data) on a blockchain

what does that really mean from a cryptographer's perspective? What security guarantees does it give? Things like availability (to which entity, under what condition and delay, with selection according to what criteria/tag), proof of origin (for one who finds that data), non-repudiation.

Is there a formal definition of a blockchain's expected properties, like we have for e.g. PRG, or a key exchange protocol?

Update: Emmanuelle Anceaume, Antonella del Pozzo,  Romaric Ludinard, Maria Potop-Butucaru, Sara Tucci-Piergiovanni's [*Blockchain Abstract Data Type*](https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-01718480v2) attempt that. But it flies too high above my head. In retrospect I should have first asked: what's a blockchain, with a simple example?

---

Update: these [NIST slides](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Presentations/NIST-Block-Chain-Research-Project/images-media/ar-dy-blockchain-combined.pdf#page=4) give a visual illustration of a minimalist blockchain:

[image: minimalist blockchain]

They also make a basic but essential distinction between

- Permissionless Blockchains, decentralized and often tied to cryptocurrencies.
- Permissioned Blockchains, involving trusted participants or perhaps an authority.

Comment: "blockchain" is vague. Is `git` a blockchain? In a trivial/literal sense, yes, but it's not necessarily able to provide any availability guarantees beyond that of the underlying storage. And it doesn't require commit signing, so no non-repudiation or proof of origin.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is one (or more) papers with [formal definitions of what a blockchain](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aeprint.iacr.org+formal+definition+blockchain) is on ePrint. However I don't have time right now to dig through the papers to find the "commonly accepted one".

Comment: @SEJPM: yet after touring a few of these, I still don't get it. That [one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/887.pdf) states _"With slight abuse of terminology we use the words ledger and blockchain inter-changeably"_, which is marginaly more precise than _transcending the barriers of language, we assimilate [smurf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs) and [schtroumpf](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Schtroumpfs)_.

Answer (score 2):

> What security guarantees does it give? Things like availability (to which entity, under what condition and delay, with selection according to what criteria/tag), proof of origin (for one who finds that data), non-repudiation.

In respect of data storage the blockchain itself (in a decentralised form) gives us [very few guarantees](https://jaxenter.com/blockchain-data-164727.html).  When it is coupled with a cryptocurrency (eg. Ehtereum) then it isn't the blockchain that provides security primarily, but the cryptocurrency via the blockchain. In such cases it is the miners of the cryptocurrency that have a vested interest to keep your data.  And it costs money.

The blockchain is useful as a means to deliver something worthwhile.  Much like torrents if there is no one seeding, then it isn't a useful means of delivery.

Answer (score 1):

> what does that really mean from a cryptographer's perspective? What security guarantees does it give? Things like availability (to which entity, under what condition and delay, with selection according to what criteria/tag), proof of origin (for one who finds that data), non-repudiation.

None of that. Those are not part of the blockchain itself - at best they are part of what is stored in the blockchain.

Basically the only guarantee is: If and only if no person (or group with common interest) controls more than half the computation power of all participants, then the blockchain protects integrity (content can't be changed).